# Error on json.loads

Tags: python, json

This is the JSON data I have:

```
{
  "id": "474676675993584",
  "about": "Official Facebook Page of GITM IEEE Society.\nWe are based out of Gurgaon Institute of Technology and Management, Gurgaon.",
  "can_post": false,
  "category": "Organization",
  "category_list": [
    {
      "id": "198503866828628",
      "name": "Organization"
    }
  ],
  "checkins": 24,
  "country_page_likes": 478,
  "cover": 
             {
                  "cover_id": "601076406686943",
                  "offset_x": 0,
                  "offset_y": 28,
                  "source": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xtp1/t31.0-8/s720x720/10321662_601076406686943_419719677923907...",
                  "id": "601076406686943"
             },
  "has_added_app": false,
  "is_community_page": false,
  "is_published": true,
  "new_like_count": 3,
  "likes": 478,
  "link": "https://www.facebook.com/ieeegitm",
  "location": 
      {
          "city": "Gurgaon",
          "country": "India",
          "latitude": 28.288555,
          "longitude": 76.860245,
          "street": "Gurgaon Institute Of Technology & Management,Bilaspur-Tauru Road, Gurgaon (Haryana)",
          "zip": "122413"
      },
  "name": "GITM IEEE",
  "offer_eligible": true,
  "parking": 
      {
          "lot": 0,
          "street": 0,
          "valet": 0
      },
  "promotion_eligible": true,
  "talking_about_count": 2,
  "unread_message_count": 0,
  "unread_notif_count": 1,
  "unseen_message_count": 0,
  "username": "ieeegitm",
  "were_here_count": 24
}
```

When I try to perform a `json.loads` on this it gives me error:

```
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads 
    return _default_decoder.decode(s) 
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366,in decode obj, 
    end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end()) 
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode obj,
    end = self.scan_once(s, idx) 
ValueError: Expecting property name: line 2 column 1 (char 2)
```

Comment: Error:
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>   
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads     return _default_decoder.decode(s)   
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366,in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Expecting property name: line 2 column 1 (char 2)

Comment: This is not a python-related question.

Comment: @Sir_FZ that Stacktrace is coming from Python. How are you trying to load the JSON OP?

Comment: @IanAuld the `json` the OP is trying to load is invalid, it's not related to `python` itself.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have some extra characters there, 
Check this tool out: http://json.parser.online.fr/

I removed the extra characters, I decoded them from unicode to hex and this is the character code: E28082.

By the way, I replaced it by space ' '.

```
{
 "id": "474676675993584",
  "about": "Official Facebook Page of GITM IEEE Society.\nWe are based out of Gurgaon Institute of Technology and Management, Gurgaon.",
  "can_post": false,
  "category": "Organization",
"category_list":[{
      "id": "198503866828628",
      "name": "Organization"}],
  "checkins": 24,
  "country_page_likes": 478,
  "cover": 
             {
                  "cover_id": "601076406686943",
                  "offset_x": 0,
                  "offset_y": 28,
                  "source": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xtp1/t31.0-8/s720x720/10321662_601076406686943_419719677923907...",
                  "id": "601076406686943"
             },
  "has_added_app": false,
  "is_community_page": false,
  "is_published": true,
  "new_like_count": 3,
  "likes": 478,
  "link": "https://www.facebook.com/ieeegitm",
  "location": 
      {
          "city": "Gurgaon",
          "country": "India",
          "latitude": 28.288555,
          "longitude": 76.860245,
          "street": "Gurgaon Institute Of Technology & Management,Bilaspur-Tauru Road, Gurgaon (Haryana)",
          "zip": "122413"
  },
  "name": "GITM IEEE",
  "offer_eligible": true,
  "parking": 
      {
          "lot": 0,
          "street": 0,
          "valet": 0
},  "promotion_eligible": true,
  "talking_about_count": 2,
  "unread_message_count": 0,
  "unread_notif_count": 1,
  "unseen_message_count": 0,
  "username": "ieeegitm",
  "were_here_count": 24
}
```

If you like to see the characters yourself, copy and paste it in notepad++ to reveal them.